# SharePoint server 2019 on-premise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, 2019, onedrive

I have one issue regarding to the custom tiles on SharePoint server 2019 on-premise. I have read this document [Custom Tiles in SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-server-2016) and followed each step, but the result is that the custom tile it appears on SharePoint site and does not appear on OneDrive site.

Please if anyone did face this kind of problem and solve it respond to me.

Comment: It's not mean to be extended to OneDrive !

Answer (score 0):

The custom tiles are only for Sharepoint and will not be propagated into OneDrive, if my answer helped, do mark my answer as accepted, thanks!